# Neo4j vs OrientDB vs Titan

Tags: data-mining, graphs, databases, social-network-analysis

I am working on a data-science project related on social relationship mining and need to store data in some graph databases. Initially I chose Neo4j as the database. But it seams Neo4j doesn't scale well. The alternative I found out are Titan  and oriebtDB. I have gone through [this](http://db-engines.com/en/system/Neo4j%3BOrientDB%3BTitan) comparison on these three Databases, But I would like to get more details on  these databases. So Could some one help me in choosing the best one. Mainly I would like to compare performance, scaling, on line documentation/tutorials available, Python library support, query language complexity and graph algorithm support of these databases. Also is there any other good database options ?

Comment: Also consider Graphlab (python based): http://graphlab.com/products/create/overview.html
Here's a good blog post about it as well:
http://bugra.github.io/work/notes/2014-04-06/graphs-databases-and-graphlab/
I can't help you with the Titan vs oriebtDB discussion though.  Hopefully someone will chime in with that.

Comment: Also possible to use Spark and GraphX

Comment: This article shows some details on scalability, special advantage for Titan.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/CpPh42ukfH4

Comment: No, it's not; GraphX is not a database.

Comment: Since this was couple of months back, I assume you made some progress. Why not add your own answer (here or elsewhere?)

Comment: Hi @Jayan as per our use-case we were initially thinking of storing entire data on Neo4j, but finally we choose MongoDB as the central database and stick with Neo4j  for analyzing relationships only (not as central DB). And also we are exploring with Spark and Graphlab

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to keep overall Data pipelines and Machine learning pipelines in mind. For which you need a robust framework to move data between table like and graph like storage apart from powerful distributed processing. From my understanding Spark GraphX is promising to build these pipelines. Joseph Gonzalez's (one of the creator of GraphLab from CMU) talk on GraphX on youtube is worth watching.